# Displaying the user's favorite products in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Displaying the user's favorite products in Django

When I want to display the user's favorite products, the query result does not display anything and returns me None.  Actually, I want to show the user which products he has added to his favorite list

```
My model, view and address Url as follows

my model:

class UserWishlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, related_name='user_favourite')
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='product_favourite', blank=True, )
my url :

 path('wish/', views.wish, name='wish'),

my view:

def wish(request):
    data = UserWishlist.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'home/test.html', {'data': data})

my template :
{{ data.products.name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

{{ data.products.name }} return a list  but you didn't use a loop to list it out, right?
You should use

```
{% for product in data.products.all%}
{{product.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

instead of it.

Comment: When I use the filter instead of the get and loop it, nothing is displayed.

Comment: It should be `data.products.all`

Comment: Hmm... I forgot it. Thanks for mentions

Answer (score 1):

Your `products` is a `ManyToManyField`, which returns `QuerySet`, so you have to treat it as it is a list. You should render it more likely like this (assuming, that `data` is `UserWishlist` object):

```
{% for product in data.products.all %}
    {{ product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If an answer is working for you, tick it as correct, so we know that issue has been solved. Otherwise give some feedback, if it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
{% for product in data.products.all %}
{{ product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```